# Numpy array manipulation;

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with the values.
z = [ 0.36244774  0.9659823  -0.24148737  0.73217936  0.61693335  0.02681095
0.52018096  0.72859236  0.7909905   0.27065993  0.32387775  1.0291859
0.92064491  0.43546447  0.57365784  0.48502579  0.35334513  0.26714324
0.79627282  0.62755723  0.76797376  0.43627165  0.88256845  1.04935857
0.46092977  1.00267849  0.30381141  0.95017402  0.49757017  0.12101592
1.00928452  0.31809237 -1.77263299  0.72214728  1.22538794  0.92354368
0.58799451  0.90665158  1.06255469  0.64028755  0.45188614  0.19005973
0.39103807  1.15312816  0.30531509  0.80580299  0.40759135 ]

I want to convert it to another array R with the condition that
`enter code here` R[i] = Alive
if :
z[i] > 0.5
else :
R[i] =Dead.`

I have tried this but it gives the error: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous".

```
res=[]
for i in range(len(ridge_sig)):
  if ridge_sig[i] < 0.5:
    res.append("Alive\n")
  else:
    res.append("Dead\n").
```

Comment: Tell us about `ridge_sig`.  You show a `z` which looks like it's 1d.  But the error indicates that `ridge_sig[i]` for at least one `i` (e.g. 0) is still an array, not single number.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list comprehension into a numpy array.

Try `np.array(['Alive' if i > 0.5 else 'Dead' for i in z])`.